# How can serilize Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException with new MongoDB driver version 2.24.0?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

the below class

```
public class FailedRequestLog
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public object Errors{ get; set; }
}
```

`
use to log failed request in MonogDB in .net8 and the error

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'An error occurred while serializing the Errors property of class MyProject.FailedRequestLog: 
Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.'
```

raised on Errors field set to DbUpdateException
`_collection.InsertOneAsync(newEntity)`  when use MongoDB.Driver Version=2.24.0  .
how can serilize Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException with new MongoDB driver version 2.24.0?

it is work in MongoDB Driver Version=2.18.0  .

Comment: tank you. it is ok. @dododo